# flask app getting acces denied from mysql connection

Tags: python, mysql, database, flask

i have a mysql database registration form in my flask application, however when i test it out and type in some valid credentials i get an acces denied error with using password no (even though i type in a password), here is my connection code:

```
app = Flask(__name__)

#config for MySQL db
app.config['MySQL_HOST'] = 'localhost'
app.config['MySQL_USER'] = 'root'
app.config['MySQL_PASSWORD'] = '****'
app.config['MySQL_DB'] = 'myflaskapp'
app.config['MySQL_CURSORCLASS'] = 'DictCursor'
#init MYSQL
mysql = MySQL(app)

Projects = Projects()
```

here is my registration flask method:

```
@app.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
form = RegisterForm(request.form)
if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
    name = form.name.data
    email = form.email.data
    username = form.username.data
    password = sha256_crypt.encrypt(str(form.password.data))
```

i have validated that the actual database exists in MySQL through the command line, and i can also access it, however when i try with my flask app, it fails.

Comment: **WARNING**: A high-speed hash like SHA256 is *completely* inadequate for storing passwords. At the *absolute minimum* use [Bcrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt).

Comment: Bcrypt is better than SHA256?

Comment: By a factor of a million. Literally. SHA256 is trivial to crack, especially if unsalted, where [cracking programs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) can smash through millions of permutations per second. Bcrypt is painfully slow on purpose and can be made even more difficult if you prefer, enough that most crackers can only do *dozens* per second.

Comment: okay thank you very much i will be sure to use Bcrypt instead of SHA256, but first i just need to access the db.

Comment: Are you sure those are the correct configuration parameter keys? I think the lower case `y` is confusing things. [The documentation](http://flask-mysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) specifies all-caps.

Comment: @tadman, yes i get an NameError: name 'MYSQL' is not defined otherwise, the thing the is strange is that the error, says access denied for user kristoffer@localhost using password 'NO', which is strange, because i would of course want to access the database with the user root?

Comment: I'd advise against using `root` for anything other than your local development machine. Always provision a user specifically for your application. That being said, I'm not sure the lower-case `y` is valid if you're using Flask-MySQL.

Comment: i'm sorry i missed, what you where saying. You where absolutely right, the lowercase y in 'MYSQL_HOST' etc. was the error, but thank you where much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The configuration parameters need to be all-caps as per [the documentation](http://flask-mysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/):

```
app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = 'localhost'
app.config['MYSQL_USER'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = '****'
app.config['MYSQL_DB'] = 'myflaskapp'
app.config['MYSQL_CURSORCLASS'] = 'DictCursor'
```

In the original code there's a lower-case `y`.